# Convergence in distribution of random variables question

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

$X, X_1, X_2,\ldots $ are real random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq x)\to \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ whenever $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$.

Why does $X_n\stackrel{L}{\to} X$? At the least, where would I begin?

Comment: Yeah, but how do I extend the given statement to hold true regardless of the value of $P(X=x)$?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/fall2003/lectures/pages16to22.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ of random variables is said to converge in distribution, or converge weakly, or converge in law to a random variable $X$ if
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)=F(x)
$$
for every number $x\in\mathbb R$ at which $F$ is continuous, where $F_n(x)=\mathbb P(X_n\le x)$ and $F(x)=\mathbb P(X\le x)$.

Thus, we need to show that $F(x)$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$. $F$ is continuous from the right, so we need to investigate continuity from the left. Since 
$$
\mathbb P(X=x)=F(x)-\lim_{y\uparrow x}F(y),
$$
we have that $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ if and only if $F(x)=\lim_{y\uparrow x}F(y)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen I added the definition of convergence in distribution. It may help to see the relation.

Comment: Nevermind my comment, I took it for granted that the definition of convergence in distribution was ${\rm E}[f(X_n)]\to{\rm E}[f(X)]$ for continuous, bounded $f$. This doesn't seem to be the definition the OP is working with. Sorry about the fuzz.

Comment: @StefanHansen No problem. These two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the definition of what is the convergence. There is also a theorem (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_en_loi, can't find the english version) that says that you need to prove that $P(X_n \in A) -> P(X \in A)$ for any A an open

Comment: Are you talking about the portmanteau theorem?

Comment: @Glassjawed yes